# Composable Image with ticket style only on bottom

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have an image in my project where the top should have round corners and the bottom should look like a ticket. I'm new to compose btw
I'm following this tutorial [here](https://juliensalvi.medium.com/custom-shape-with-jetpack-compose-1cb48a991d42). My problem here is that I don't know how to make my top corners rounded.

Right now I have the following code

```
class TicketBottom : Shape {
override fun createOutline(
    size: Size,
    layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
    density: Density
): Outline {
    val cornerRadius = 25f

    val path = Path().apply {
        // Top left arc
        arcTo(
            rect = Rect(
                left = cornerRadius,
                top = cornerRadius,
                right = 0f,
                bottom = 0f
            ),
            startAngleDegrees = 90.0f,
            sweepAngleDegrees = -90.0f,
            forceMoveTo = false
        )
        lineTo(x = size.width - cornerRadius, y = 0f)
        // Top right arc
        arcTo(
            rect = Rect(
                left = size.width + cornerRadius,
                top = -cornerRadius,
                right = size.width + cornerRadius,
                bottom = cornerRadius
            ),
            startAngleDegrees = 180.0f,
            sweepAngleDegrees = -90.0f,
            forceMoveTo = false
        )
        lineTo(x = size.width, y = size.height - cornerRadius)
        // Bottom right arc
        arcTo(
            rect = Rect(
                left = size.width - cornerRadius,
                top = size.height - cornerRadius,
                right = size.width + cornerRadius,
                bottom = size.height + cornerRadius
            ),
            startAngleDegrees = 270.0f,
            sweepAngleDegrees = -90.0f,
            forceMoveTo = false
        )
        lineTo(x = cornerRadius, y = size.height)
        // Bottom left arc
        arcTo(
            rect = Rect(
                left = -cornerRadius,
                top = size.height - cornerRadius,
                right = cornerRadius,
                bottom = size.height + cornerRadius
            ),
            startAngleDegrees = 0.0f,
            sweepAngleDegrees = -90.0f,
            forceMoveTo = false
        )
        lineTo(x = 0f, y = cornerRadius)
    }
    return Outline.Generic(path = path)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should change your code to:

```
// Top left arc
        arcTo(
            rect = Rect(
                left = -cornerRadius,
                top = -cornerRadius,
                right = cornerRadius, // your code: 0f
                bottom = cornerRadius // your code: 0f
            ),
            startAngleDegrees = 90.0f,
            sweepAngleDegrees = -90.0f,
            forceMoveTo = false
        )
// Top right arc
        arcTo(
            rect = Rect(
                left = size.width - cornerRadius, // your code: size.width + cornerRadius
                top = -cornerRadius,
                right = size.width + cornerRadius,
                bottom = cornerRadius
            ),
            startAngleDegrees = 180.0f,
            sweepAngleDegrees = -90.0f,
            forceMoveTo = false
        )
```